# List item is not visible in fragment

Tags: android, listview

I am developing a music app. Following is the code of my songs list. When I run my app, only music artworks are showing. Other information like album name, duration is not showing in `ListView`.

[image: this is the screenshot of my app]

```
public class songs_list extends Fragment {

// Adapter that exposes data from a Cursor to a ListView widget.
private songs_list.MediaCursorAdapter mediaAdapter = null;

private String currentFile="";
private boolean isStarted = true;
private TextView selelctedFile = null;
private View v=null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Use cursor to get data from external resource

    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    // check Cursor has data or not

    if (null != cursor) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        mediaAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_layout, cursor);
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs_list, container, false);
       // TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

        ListView lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        lv.setAdapter(mediaAdapter);


    }
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return v;
}


MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();



//MediaCursorAdapter class construction (what to show )

private class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {


    public MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {

        super(context, layout, c,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID, MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION},

                new int[]{R.id.icon, R.id.title, R.id.artistname, R.id.duration});

    }



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artistname);
        TextView duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);

        // icon
        long albumid = Long.parseLong((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID))));

        Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumid);
        ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = res.openInputStream(uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        img.setImageBitmap(artwork);


        title.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE)));

        name.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ARTIST)));


        long durationInMs = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION)));

        double durationInMin = ((double) durationInMs / 1000.0) / 60.0;

        durationInMin = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(durationInMin)).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP).doubleValue();

        duration.setText("" + durationInMin);

        view.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);

        bindView(v, context, cursor);

        return v;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: is ListItem's text coloured white?

Comment: yeah that was the problem. but i am still confused like default colour is black not white.

Comment: its because of your theme

Comment: Show me view of R.layout.list_layout, parent this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the style :

```
<style name="TextColor">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

> In the layout file :

```
<TextView  style="@style/TextColor" />
```

> This will help you fix the color to any one by default which you want.

Comment: text colour was white but actually i am still confuse like we know default colour is light black. so why it is showing default text white.

Comment: you must have set the value earlier because of which the value must have been set as white.

Comment: my layout background colour was white so may be that's why my text colour was white.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments, your `ListItem`'s text color was white. Since the background color is also white, it is hard to spot white text on it. You can change your text color with:

```
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
```

or, by simply using `#000000` for black color.

If you are using DarkTheme or a style that overrides `android:textColor`,  it is normal for text to be white. Otherwise, check your `ListItem` and `ListView` layouts for text color changes. I'm doubting these:

- R.layout.list_layout
- R.layout.fragment_songs_list
- android.R.id.list